# Conflicting information about SFTP using SSH1 or SSH2

Tags: ssh, sftp

I've trying to better understand SFTP and what it does behind the scenes.

Unfortunately info out there is quite ambiguous

I was taking as truth that SFTP uses SSH2 to encrypt the channel and, since SSH2 and SSH (SSH1) are not compatible, you can't have SFTP over SSH.

However other sources in the Internet just mentioned SSH but it is never clear if they really meant SSH1 or encapsulation SSH2 info in that (Bad way to write technical article I know)

I was hoping someone could clarify that for me and hopefully help other people facing the same challenge.

Comment: Your question really isn't clear here.  If you want to know how sftp works.  Look directly at the source code, and the specs.  It isn't really reasonable to ask us to explain problems with articles when you didn't include links to those articles.  That said, the old SSHv1 protocol has been more or less dead for over a decade.  When someone says SSH without any qualifiers they almost always mean a relatively current default OpenSSH build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However other sources in the Internet just mentioned SSH but it is never clear if they really meant SSH1 or encapsulation SSH2 info in that (Bad way to write technical article I know)

By SSH is generally meant SSH-2, which is widely used quite much everywhere. SSH-1 is very old protocol that should not be used anywhere unless you are connecting to some ancient device in your isolated network.

Above that, SFTP is implemented as an file transfer protocol for SSH-2, as explicitly mentioned in the specification draft [draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-02](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-02).

Comment: I'm very new to this, great answer.